# PHP doesn't recognize PDT

Tags: php

I'm just trying to print the current time in PDT

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('PDT') );
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P')."\n";

$date2 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('PST') );
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P')."\n";
?>
```

and I get

```
2022-05-03 14:59:33 PDT -08:00
2022-05-03 14:59:33 PST -08:00
```

Why is this happening and how do I get the right time? This is PHP 7.4

Edit: I know `America/Los_Angeles` works, but that's not the point. Background: get the system time zone from a database and get the current time of that time zone. Unless there's a way to convert `PDT` to `America/Los_Angeles`?

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/0123c) and your output example is working as expected (-08:00)

Comment: Check List of Supported Timezones for PHP. https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php  _______
$date1 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Marquesas') );

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') );
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P')."\n";

$date2 = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') );
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P')."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php
// first set YOUR timezone or the Server timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');

// set current time
$date1 = new DateTime();
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P') . "\n";

// set new time zone
$newTimezone = new DateTimeZone('PST');

// change current Datetime to new timezone
$date1->setTimezone($newTimezone)

// show time
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P')."\n";

// set new time zone
$newTimezone = new DateTimeZone('EST');

// change current Datetime to new timezone
$date1->setTimezone($newTimezone)

// show time
echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e P')."\n";
```